# How to migrate from cp-enterprise-kafka:6.2.1 to cp-kafka:6.2.1 docker image? It fails for me

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, enterprise

When I change the image in docker-compose.yml from enterprise [**cp-enterprise-kafka**](https://hub.docker.com/layers/confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka/6.2.1/images/sha256-8a1b5bdeacc1a4a3bad6353caea9bfc0cacfe4a7ac3e48cd0797c3ab36032f39?context=explore) to regular [**cp-kafka**](https://hub.docker.com/layers/confluentinc/cp-kafka/6.2.1/images/sha256-870c760a9e184260c159e4f7e5b4e715be0b89726b397f709fd6ce43add34456?context=explore)

it fails to start with:

```
broker-1       | [2021-10-19 09:22:32,042] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Controller 1 epoch 38 fails to send request (type: UpdateMetadataRequest=, controllerId=1, controllerEpoch=38, brokerEpoch=7362, partitionStates=[], liveBrokers=UpdateMetadataBroker(id=1, v0Host='', v0Port=0, endpoints=[UpdateMetadataEndpoint(port=19092, host='broker-1', listener='INSIDE', securityProtocol=0), UpdateMetadataEndpoint(port=9092, host='192.168.100.14', listener='OUTSIDE', securityProtocol=0)], rack=null)) to broker broker-1:19092 (id: 1 rack: null). Reconnecting to broker. (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
broker-1       | java.io.IOException: Client was shutdown before response was read
broker-1       |        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.sendAndReceive(NetworkClientUtils.java:109)
broker-1       |        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:253)
broker-1       |        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
broker-1       | [2021-10-19 09:22:32,045] ERROR [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Controller 1 fails to send a request to broker broker-1:19092 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
broker-1       | java.lang.InterruptedException
broker-1       |        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1367)
broker-1       |        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:278)
broker-1       |        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.pause(ShutdownableThread.scala:82)
broker-1       |        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:234)
broker-1       |        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
```

My config in docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper-1
    container_name: zookeeper-1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-1:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-logs-1:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    networks:
      - mynet

  broker-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:6.2.1
    hostname: broker-1
    container_name: broker-1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: '192.168.100.14:2181'

      KAFKA_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://192.168.100.14:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: OUTSIDE

      KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE: 'LogAppendTime'

      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS: 31536000000 # 1 year

      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 192.168.100.14:9092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 192.168.100.14:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/kafka-1:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

i.e. I change only broker-1 image from cp-enterprise-kafka to cp-kafka.

I noticed that controllerEpoch is much lesser than brokerEpoch - maybe this is a reason?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you also wipe the data volumes, then what happens?

Comment: it's not an option to wipe data, that's why I'm asking this question :-)
but maybe zookeeper. I know that kafka stores consumers offsets in the broker. is it safe to wipe zookeper data?

Comment: Zookeeper data stores the actual topic names and configurations... So no. In any case, please add logs as text, not an image

Comment: I don't know how but I resolved my issue with manipulation zookeeper data, I copied existing to backup place, then start then got error wrong cluster from broker, then copied all back and run again - bingo! :-D

Comment: Nice. Feel free to provide your solution below rather than as a comment

Comment: Added how it worked for me, but not sure about steps (maybe redudant steps with backup). Issue was 100% in zookeeper.

Comment: Please revert the question section and post in the box below as an answer

Comment: I've rolled back your question since you've now correctly posted the answer as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED (but don't know how exactly):**

1. stopped zookeeper and broker
2. copy all zookeeper data (backup)
3. start zookeeper and broker and got this (wrong cluster):

```
broker-1       | [2021-10-19 09:25:25,648] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
broker-1       | kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: The Cluster ID MlRI76IVQ8y4nTZgigyUGw doesn't match stored clusterId Some(HXaFk1peQcaR23TAqh0Z2g) in meta.properties. The broker is trying to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.
broker-1       |        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:218)
broker-1       |        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
broker-1       |        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

4. stopped zookeeper and broker
5. copied (backed up previously) zookeeper data back
6. started... and all starts ok!

*Maybe* even zookeeper data backup not needed at all and it's fine just to change broker's cluster.id inside /var/lib/kafka/data/meta.properties